# Session getting lost after redirection from payment gateway to wordpress in php

Tags: php, wordpress, session

In WordPress plugin, I am using `$woocommerce->session->set()` & `$woocommerce->session->get()` for setting and fetching the **session** data respectively. In my **payment getaway plugin**, I am setting some order data in the session before redirecting to the payment gateway so that once the payment is complete I can utilize those session data for verification. But when my WordPress website redirects to the payment gateway and after payment completion when it redirects back to the website those session data will not be present. Can anyone please help here!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most often this is a problem with the `SameSite` attribute of the session cookie not being set correctly.

Comment: How to resolve this @CBroe

Comment: If the keyword means nothing to you yet, then the first step would be to go read up on it.